# How to catch @RequestParams when the user pass a empty value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, kotlin

I am trying to do a Spring MVC RestController with kotlin,
but I am having an hard time with RequestParams with LocalDatetime

```
@GetMapping
fun getParams(@RequestParam(required = true) endDate: LocalDateTime)
```

If I don't specify the param `localhost:8080/` it gives an error that can be caught in a ControllerAdvice but if I specify a empty value `localhost:8080/endDate=` it will give me 
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method net.agroop.deviceapi.controllers.DeviceController.getAirParams, parameter endDate`

I found no way to catch that error in the ControllerAdvice because it is a kotlin error, I think.

I tried with other types like Date and it also gives error. If I use String it works because String can be empty.
Also, if I specify LocalDateTime? as nullable it works but then I have to catch the error in the Controller in every RequestMapping and not in the ControllerAdvice.

Comment: Do you have an `@ControllerAdvice` set up?

Comment: Specify the param as nullable, or give it a default value in the annotation.

Comment: Don't use `@RequestParam` but rather use a form object which has a field `endDate` and use regular validation rules like `@NotNull` to validate the form. This also integrates with Spring I18N and you can provide nice error messages as well.

Comment: Yes @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas i have it set up and it caches if i dont pass the parameter or an invalid date, but it will not if the parameter is passed but is empty/null

Comment: I know @gidds but i am trying to catch all errors in ControllerAdvice

Comment: I tried that @M.Deinum but it gives the same error, because kotlin have some form of null checking that i can't catch :(

Comment: Make the field optional instead of always required to be `null` then it should work. Unless Kotlin also interprets the `@NotNull` but I doubt that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself.
Just had to had a `Converter<S, T>` Component to handle the date conversion

```
@Component
class LocalDateConverter : Converter<String, LocalDateTime> {
    override fun convert(source: String): LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(source, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
}
```

And now i can handle the exception using:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException::class)
fun handleMethodArgumentTypeMismatch(ex: MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException, request: WebRequest) =
```

Answer (score 0):

To get out of the exception, just make the attribute of your model null, that is, `endDate: LocalDateTime?`

```
@GetMapping
fun getParams(@RequestParam(required = true) endDate: LocalDateTime?)
```

And to validate empty values you can use [`@field:NotEmpty`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62374746/5279996) in your `data class` with [Hibernate Validator](https://hibernate.org/validator/).

GL

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62468677/5279996)